# Python - Checking if Drive is Mounted Not Working

Tags: python

I'm running into a strange issue and I'm not sure what is going on at this point. I'm trying to check to use Python to check to see if a device is mounted.

The following code returns true:

```
disk_check = os.path.ismount("/dev")
print(disk_check)
```

But the second I try to find anything else, it always returns false, even if I run diskutil and can see /dev/disk1s1:

```
disk_check = os.path.ismount("/dev/disk1s1")
print(disk_check)
```

Would anyone be able to provide any additional insight into what might be going on?

Comment: Looks like [`ismount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount) just checks if a directory is a mounting point. That is why `os.path.ismount("/dev/")` returns `True` but checking if a mounted disk is a mounting point returns `False`.

Comment: Are you trying to access a usb device?

Comment: Try in your terminal `ls /dev/tty.*` or `ls /dev/cu.*` and see if your pendrive appears. If so, add this to its name (e.g. /dev/tty.disk1s1)

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to access an external drive. Would 'ismount' not be appropriate to use?

Comment: I think [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) is what you want. If you want to be sure that it is a mounted device *and* a dir, then you can check `os.path.ismount("/dev/")` before `os.path.isdir("/dev/disk1s1/")`

Comment: @mgmussi those commands in terminal didn't work at all.

Comment: @Moosefeather I'll give that a shot right now. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Moosefeather same thing happens with `os.path.isdir`. I get true when I'm at `/dev` but it goes false the second I add in `/dev/disk1s1`.

Comment: @JordanTaylor try `ls /dev*` instead and see if you can find what is the actual name of your mounted device (it only works if mounted and you cant be in an environment)

Comment: @mgmussi doing that brought up two columns. If I'm looking for `disk1s1`, the left column is showing `dfsfuse35` and the right column is `rdisk1s1`. What one should I be looking at? I've put both of them in there, but still getting `False`.

Comment: If it helps at all, I'm doing this on macOS.

Comment: @JordanTaylor It's possible your port is not being recognised, and it can be a driver problem or a port problem, and for the second one, you might want to do an [SMC reset](https://osxdaily.com/2015/08/09/mac-usb-ports-not-working-fix/)

Comment: @JordanTaylor then that means there is no mounted disk in `/dev/` called `disk1s1`, perhaps it's actually `rdisk1s1`? Edit: looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works for me.

If I check it this way, I'm getting the results I'm looking for

```
disk_check = os.path.isdir("/Volumes/LaCie")
print(disk_check)
```

This should be more than sufficient for what I'm looking for. Thank you everyone for your feedback and assistance!